# Как создать Dictionary для хранения замыканий в Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

У меня есть класс Blocker, в нем есть свойтсво blocks которое является словарем, где ключ это строка с именем класса а значение это замыкание(кложур).

Для добавления нового блока я использую метод addBlock в который передается два параметра. Первый - тип объекта, второй - кложур. Проблема в том что после присваивания blocks["(type)"] = completion as? MyBlock , словарь blocks остается пустым.

Дженерики я использую для того чтобы в теле кложура можно было работать с объектом. Например для обьекта типа UIView задать backgroundColor.

```
import UIKit

class Blocker {

    typealias MyBlock<T> = (_ view: T) -> Void

    var blocks = [String: MyBlock<Any>]()

    func addBlock<T>(type: T.Type, completion: @escaping MyBlock<T>) {
        blocks["\(type)"] = completion as? MyBlock<Any>
        print(blocks["\(type)"])
    }

}

let blocker = Blocker()
blocker.addBlock(type: UIView.self) { view in
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```

*Пример работает в Swift Playground.*

**Если убрать дженерики и сделать везде тип Any. То это хорошо работает. Но приходиться в теле самого блока делать приведение типа. Как вариант, но хочу знать есть ли вариант решения с дженериками.**

```
blocker.addBlock(type: UIView.self) { view in
    let v = (view as! UIView)
    v.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Причина:**

`MyBlock<UIView>`, который передается в качестве параметра, и `MyBlock<Any>`, который хранится в dictionary - это разные типы. Поэтому оператор приведения типов `as?` используемый в `completion as? MyBlock<Any>` возвращает `nil` и в dictionary ничего в итоге не сохраняется.

**Решение:**

Стоит определиться, какое желаемое поведение, в случае вызова метода не с `UIView`, а с другим объектом.
Например, если для Вашей задачи подходит игнорирование вызова, можно при присваивании значения сделать дополнительную проверку с игнорированием:

```swift
func addBlock<T>(type: T.Type, completion: @escaping MyBlock<T>) {
    blocks["\(type)"] = {
        guard let value = $0 else { return }
        completion(value)
    }
    print(blocks["\(type)"])
}
```

**PS**: Дополнительно, могу порекомендовать немного поменять название класса, так как `Blocker` - это что-то, что блокирует. В Вашем же случае класс используется для сохранения замыканий (они-же блоки в терминах objc). `BlockStorage`, `ClosureStorage` или `ClosureDictionary` было бы чуть-чуть понятней.